# CPU time for hive query run through oozie

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am running an oozie workflow in which I have hive action. How can I get the CPU time taken by the query. 
If a hive query is submitted through Hive CLI then it shows **cumulative CPU time** but that can not be seen in logs for Map Reduce or oozie for Hive action.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the corresponding MR job that got submitted in Resource Manager. Open the syslogs of parent job. You can find all console information there.